# Rendering up to X elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'got pretty huge json file containing half million records and I want user to be able to filter through it to find what they want. However, rendering 250000 `<li>` is not possible for most of the people.

Is there any way I could force react to only render up to, let's say, 50 elements.

Currently I render it this way:

```
   const dataList = data.filter(data => {
       return data.A.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
   }).map(data => {
       return(
        <li className="list-group-item" key={uuid()} >{data.A}</li>
       )
   })
```

Comment: react-virtualized is what I think will help you https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/

Answer (score 1):

As you're filtering, you *could* do a [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) after the `filter`:

```
return data.filter(/*...*/).slice(0, 50).map(/*...*/);
```

The first argument is where to start, the second is where to stop. You could make those variables so the user can page through the records.

```
return data.filter(/*...*/).slice(from, to).map(/*...*/);
```

**But**, that means you're filtering through all the elements even when you already have the 50 you want to show. Instead, we probably want to stop when you have the elements you need; and if we're breaking the streaming paradigm, we may as well fold in the `map` as well:

```
const dataList = [];
let skip = from;
const max = to - from;
const filterLowerCase = filterText.toLowerCase(); // Do this *once*
data.some(function(entry) {
    if (entry.A.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterLowerCase) !== -1) {
        if (skip > 0) {
            --skip;
        } else {
            dataList.push(<li className="list-group-item" key={uuid()} >{entry.A}</li>);
            if (dataList.length == max) {
                return true; // Stop `some`, we have enough
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Hmmmm, could go either way, but I get you're right. Good point, I'll call it out.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Actually, more efficient not to use `filter` then `slice` anyway, I'll fix it.

Comment: Sounded too simple to work, the website still crashes when it tries to render even 10 elements so I guess React is still trying to load everything, then slice.

Comment: @MazMat: Well, your starting point in the question is that `data` contains all the entries, so that's an invariant, but no, React won't magically try to *render* them all with the above.

Comment: @MazMat, if it still happens it may not be due to rendering but filtering on such huge data, I suppose, you need to optimize the filtering logic, use debounce on input and if still doesn't work try to do filtering on backend instead of frontend and if the resultant data is huge, make use of react-virtualized to render the results

Comment: Edited answer appears to be working, although I will need to study this code to understand it, thank you :)